# HTTP calls from spark map function ensuring single instance of HttpClient

Tags: java, apache-spark, httpclient

I have a dataset and I have to call an API for each row of the dataset. I am using a Map function for this.
Inside the map function, I do the API call and return a new object .

I am able to do API calls by creating new HttpClient for each call.

`HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();`client is initialised and used inside map function,

However, when I try to use a single instance of Http Client, my API calls are failing with.

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid use of BasicClientConnManager: connection still allocated.Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.`

I am using following approach to ensure single object of HttpClient.

```
    private static HttpClient httpClient;
    public static HttpClient gethttpClient() {
        if (httpClient == null) {
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        }
        return httpClient;
    }
```

And calling gethttpClient() to getmake API calls. However, it is giving the above error.

What can be the correct way to do API calls from map function in java spark.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to avoid excess creation of HttpClient obects and so the method but only way out of this is to iterate the rows on batches and use `new DefaultHttpClient()` for each batch. 
`dataset` is of type `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset`

```
dataset.foreachPartition( dataSetBatch -> {
            DefaultHttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
            if(dataSetBatch.hasNext()) {
                dataSetBatch.next();
                // invoke submit hhtp request here
            }
            http.close();

        });
```